# Java Web Start Application: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpMethod

Tags: java, jar, java-web-start, noclassdeffounderror, jnlp

I am getting following error in Java Web Start Application.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpMethod
```

My JNLP file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp codebase="http://localhost:7001/myapp/" href="">
    <information>
        <title>My App</title>
        <vendor>Something</vendor>
    </information>
   <resources>
        <j2se version="1.6+" />
        <jar href="applets/myApp.jar" main="true" />
        <jar href="applets/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar" main="false" />
        <jar href="applets/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar" main="false" />
        <jar href="applets/commons-codec-1.2.jar" main="false" />
        <jar href="applets/json-2.0.jar" main="false" />
        <jar href="applets/commons-io-1.1.jar" main="false" />
    </resources>
    <application-desc name="app1" main-class="com.test.MainClass" width="1200" height="850">
        <argument>abc</argument>
     </application-desc>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

MANIFEST.MF entries in myApp.jar:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.6
Trusted-Library: true
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
Class-Path: commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar 
 commons-logging-1.0.4.jar commons-codec-1.2.jar commons-io-1.1.jar json-2.0.jar commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar 
Application-Name: My Applicaton
Permissions: all-permissions
Created-By: 1.7.0_79-b15 (Oracle Corporation)
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
Codebase: *
```

I can see the jar file "commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar" in resources in Java Control Panel (Java Cache Viewer), but when my application use HttpMethod class it throws exception.
All jars are signed in my application. 
I am getting same error with other third-party jar files also.

Any help would be appreciated very much!

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: `applets/myApp.jar` Is this JNLP launching an applet or an application? Either way, the `application-desc` is wrong, but how it's wrong depends on the answer to that question.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Andrew. Previously, our application was an applet, but after chrome stop supporting applet, we migrated our applet for JNLP and we also changed it to the application instead of an applet.

Comment: @Andrew, Can you please guide me regarding this issue? What's wrong with application-desc?

Comment: *"Can you please guide me.."* What do you think the first comment was about?